# Symfony preSubmit form event changes not retained in controller/persist

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm having to make changes to collections (Symfony form `CollectionType`) to respect ordering and entity removal and I'm using a `preSubmit` event listener to make the changes as per [this issue suggestion](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7468#issuecomment-213411710). However the changes aren't making it back to the controller/persistence.

The data is correct after the `preSubmit` and being set on the event using `$event->setData($data)` but the changes are not retained after submitting in `$form->getData()`

My pre submit abstract class:

```
abstract class AbstractEntityFormType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, [$this, 'onPreSubmit']);
    }

    /**
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();
        $document = $form->getData();

        foreach ($form->all() as $field) {
            /** @var FormInterface $field */
            $fieldName = $field->getName();
            if ($field->getConfig()->getType()->getInnerType() instanceof CollectionType) {
                // .. DO ALL TRANSFORMATION
            }
        }
        $event->setData($data);
    }
}
```

When I dump `$data` here, everything is correct.

FormType extending this `AbstractEntityFormType` class:

```
class DocumentType extends AbstractEntityFormType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     * @return void
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        /** ADD THE LISTENER **/
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('title', TextType::class, [
            'required'    => true,
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank([
                    'message' => '"title" is empty',
                ]),
            ],
        ]);

        $builder->add('symptoms', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type'     => SymptomType::class,
            'allow_add'      => true,
            'allow_delete'   => true,
            'by_reference'   => false,
        ]);

        $builder->add('tags', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type'   => TagType::class,
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ]);

        $builder->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     * @return void
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Document::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

My controller action:

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @param int|null $documentId
 * @return Response
 */
public function formAction(Request $request, int $documentId = null)
{
    if (!$documentId) {
        $document = new Document();
    } else {
        try {
            $document = $this->documentService->getDocument($documentId);
        } catch (InvalidDocumentException $e) {
            return new NotFoundResponse('Document not found');
        }
    }

    $document = $this->setAuthor($document);

    $form = $this->formFactory->create(DocumentType::class, $document);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $document = $this->documentService->createDocument($form->getData());

        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('ui.document.view', [
            'documentId' => $document->getId()
        ]));
    }

    return $this->templating->renderResponse(
        '@KBS/Document/form.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]
    );
}
```

When I dump `$form->getData()` before persisting the document with the service, the data is incorrect - it hasn't been affected by the `preSubmit`. What am I missing?

FYI, this is using Symfony 3.2 base components.

> ***Update***

Thanks to @LBT, I'm a bit closer but still facing some issues. Using this approach in the controller, I am able to get the correct data out of the request at the point of submitting the form:

```
public function formAction(Request $request, int $documentId = null)
{
    if (!$documentId) {
        $document = new Document();
    } else {
        try {
            $document = $this->documentService->getDocument($documentId);
        } catch (InvalidDocumentException $e) {
            return new NotFoundResponse('Document not found');
        }
    }

    $document = $this->setAuthor($document);

    $form = $this->formFactory->create(DocumentType::class, $document);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $document = $this->documentService->createDocument($form->getData());

            return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('ui.document.view', [
                'documentId' => $document->getId()
            ]));
        }
    }

    return $this->templating->renderResponse(
        '@KBS/Document/form.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]
    );
}
```

However, `$form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));` is also saving incorrect (original) data before being transformed. Even though the data in the request is correct:

```
/var/www/html/src/Controller/DocumentController.php:94:
array (size=8)
  'title' => string 'Tag test' (length=8)
  'symptoms' =>
    array (size=1)
      0 =>
        array (size=3)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'title' => string 'The smell is terrible' (length=21)
          'description' => string 'pew' (length=3)
  'tags' =>
    array (size=4)
      0 =>
        array (size=1)
          'title' => string 'Volvo' (length=5)
      1 =>
        array (size=1)
          'title' => string 'Engine' (length=6)
      2 =>
        array (size=1)
          'title' => string 'BMW' (length=3)
      3 =>
        array (size=1)
          'title' => string 'Funky' (length=5)
```

Feel like I'm getting closer but I don't seem to be able to use this request data as [suggested in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/direct_submit.html#calling-form-submit-manually) for some reason.

Comment: what does $request->getContent() deliver?

Comment: `$request->getContent()` is an empty string. `$request->request` has the correct `$data` array though. so it seems it's making it back, just not with the form

Comment: that's what I meant - so you can continue your investitation from there

Comment: Have updated my question - seem to be getting closer now. Just battling with some new problems. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction

Comment: is there a reason why you use PRE_SUBMIT instead of [PRE_SET_DATA](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-listener-to-a-form-class)

Comment: Argh - I realised why I was getting the string/NULL error, - i'd added an extra `form` key during debug. I've removed this now and it saves the form but without the updated data. So it's the same problem. I can look at PRE_SET_DATA - I've based it on the suggestion made in the github issue on the repo. I'm in serious danger of just going down a rabbit hole at the moment.

Comment: I had the same problem, because I was adding fields to parent form in pre_submit of child form. Could you post what are you doing in `// .. DO ALL TRANSFORMATION`?

Comment: Yes @ste is right you need to set the data in $data = $event->getData(); and try using SUBMIT instead of PRE_SUBMIT

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to share with us ?..

Comment: Not really - I've not got access to the code anymore but ended up doing something horrible with a DoctrineEventSubscriber and lots of UnitOfWork nastiness. Not something I'd recommend as pretty much untestable and unreadable, nor could I recreate it. Sorry!